# Remove substring only if followed by space or nothing (i.e. end of string) - Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

Let's say I want to remove the word "tree" in every string in a Pandas dataframe column.

I would specify the substring(s) I want removed in a list. And then use `replace` and `join` on the column, as per below:

```
remove_list = ['\tree\s']

df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('|'.join(remove_list ), '', regex=True).str.strip()
```

The reason I add a `\s` to tree is because there may be words like treehouse or backstreet. So I want to replace the word only if it ends with a space, so that I don't end up with words like "house" or "backst".

However I noticed that when I run this code, it misses "tree"s that are at the end of the string, because there is no space after it. Hence, it doesn't get removed. Any idea on how I can account for those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think the logic you want here is:

```py
remove_list = ['tree']
terms = r'\s*\b(?:' + '|'.join(remove_list) + r')\b\s*'

df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(terms, ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
```

Note that the regex pattern used above is, for a one word term list, `\s*\b(?:tree)\b\s*`.  This will match only the exact word `tree` and not when `tree` appears as a substring of another word.  We also attempt to grab any spaces on either side of the word.  Then, we replace with just a single space, and trim the column to make sure there are no stray spaces at the start or end.

**Edit:**

To address the edge case put forth by @user2357112, consider the following input:

```
apple tree tree squirrel
```

In this case, the above solution would leave behind two spaces in between `apple` and `squirrel`.  We can get around this by expanding our regex pattern to allow for multiple consecutive keyword matches:

```py
terms = r'\s*\b(?:' + '|'.join(remove_list) + r')\b(?: \b(?:' + '|'.join(remove_list) + r'))*\b\s*'
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(terms, ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
```

Here we are using the following regex pattern:

```regex
\s*\b(?:tree)\b(?: \b(?:tree))*\b\s*
```

Comment: Isn't this going to turn `"a tree frog"` into `"afrog"`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Not at all.  The replacement is a single space, so `a frog` would be the result.

Comment: Ah, I see the space now. Won't that result in excess spaces if multiple terms from `remove_list` show up consecutively, though?

Comment: For example, an input of `"apple tree tree squirrel"` results in an output with two spaces between `apple` and `squirrel`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica This appears to be an edge case which is not a major concern for the OP.  That being said, I have updated my answer with an option covering your edge case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks again for your answer. Just to add to user2357112's question, if ```remove_list``` contains more than one word, there may be the off chance that a double space is created if two of those words show up concurrently. But you did mention in your original answer that it was for a one word list.

Comment: @sudden_clarity_clarence I have given an alternative at the bottom of my answer which covers this edge case.